# Using Selenium in Python to click and open the next page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the data from a website. I choose selenium to do that and there are 54 pages. However, after the button of next page is located and clicked, the page is still the first one (It should display page 2 without new tab or new window). How can I fix it? Really need help.

Here's the relevant code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver'))
driver.get('https://cryptorank.io/ico')
time.sleep(3)
next_button_xpath = '//*[@id="root-container"]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/button[7]'
next_button_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, next_button_xpath)
next_button_element.click()
```

Comment: Your xpath match on the "..." on pagination

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is incorrectly selecting the `...` element. Make a tiny tweak to it in order to select the "2":

```
//*[@id="root-container"]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/button[3]
```

Also, this one is likely more robust and more clear:

```
//*[@id="root-container"]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/button[*/text()="2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**ROOT CAUSE:**

```
//*[@id="root-container"]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/button[7]
```

Your above XPath expression is locating the 3 dots shown below. Obviously clicking on it won't do anything. This is the root cause of the issue.

[image]

**SOLUTION:** Construct the XPath expression which will locate the second, third page and so on. Something like below. This expression will locate the second page link. For third page, just change number to `3` and so on.

```
//span[text()='2']
```

**Full code**: Note that I have replaced `time.sleep(3)`(which is not recommended) with selenium's `waits`

```
driver.get('https://cryptorank.io/ico')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
next_button_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='2']")))
next_button_element.click()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```